# What is this DFA means?

Tags: finite-automata, dfa, computation-theory

There is a DFA.

[image]

But I don't know this DFA means.

I want to know this DFA's Regular expression and description

(Description like 'this automata accept suffix is 011)

Blue state is start state and red states are accept states.

Comment: What even are the accept states...

Comment: finite state mean accept state...

Comment: example, it accept 1, 10, 11, but 110 doesn't accept

Answer (score 0):

see the link below....it will tell about DFA.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton
```